# Suitable analysis for data, or transformations required for analysis? Categorical & binary data

Tags: r, regression, data-analysis

I am looking to conduct an analysis to determine how effective different survey methods are in detecting burrows. I am unsure how to conduct the analysis in its current form, or whether it needs to be transformed into a more suitable format.

I want to analyse whether vegetation type and or activity level affects the different survey methods ability to detect the burrows, then compare the three survey methods (LIDAR, Drone, Ground). I will be using the latest version of RStudio, and have attempted a singular logistic regression between one survey method and vegetation, but still unsure how to compare between the different survey methods.

I have provided a snippet of the data below.

Any tips to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

[Wombat Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OqIE.png)

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for help with statistical analysis are typically better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ; also, I strongly recommend posting a sample of your data (not a picture) per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm also voting to migrate this to [stats.se]. While perhaps less required there than here, providing sample data is important ... and by that I mean sample data that doesn't require us to transcribe the data you have available (even including a dozen lines of raw CSV data in a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) can be helpful).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right place, will fix it up when I get the time